# Why is for-loop sometimes skipping some iterations?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In the function below, the for loop sometimes skips one iteration.

In some rare cases, I've also found it skipping two iterations.
This sometimes breaks my code and would probably affect my future codes, if my understanding of the for loop remains incomplete.

I further looked into the matter and tried the same with a while loop and found out that this problem doesn't happens if a while loop is used.

Why is the for-loop sometimes skipping some iterations ?

```
function forLoopString(len)
{
    var string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    var character = '', 
        randomString = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        character = string.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length-1) + 0); 
        randomString += character;
    }

    if(randomString.length < len)
    {
        console.log('Less than required length!');
        randomString = randomString + '5';
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

[***JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/DevangMstryls/ojbp0evz/)

Comment: Why the `+0`? Seems rather unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop shown *won't* "skip" any iterations, but will iterate from `[0, len)` as told to do.

However, a negative argument to `charAt` makes it seem like it "skips" because `"foo".charAt(-1) == ""`. The same empty-string result holds for any out-of-bounds to [String.charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt):

> .. *If* the index you supply [to charAt] is out of range, JavaScript *returns an empty string*.

A correction that yields an always-valid index would merely be `Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length)`, *without* the -1.

Although this is slightly biased (for anyone that really cares) this is 'correct' because Math.random returns a number in the range `[0, 1)`. Thus `Math.random() * len` returns a value from `[0, len)`; and as an Integer in the same interval after the floor.

Also, it would be good to choose more useful variable names.. and, as Ed points out the +0 is irrelevant because `Math.floor` returns a (integer) number.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It works exactly as expected.

'useful variable names' ... like how ?

Comment: @Devang Well, I know it's a "string"! (This can be viewed as a form of [Systems Hungarian Notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian)) Let the variable name tell me *what* it represents. Something like `randomSet` or `alphabet` (not being strictly tied to "A-Z" English alphabet, but rather the alphabet the result comes from, of course) - although there are plenty of other, and possible better, names available. This change would make the variable name "add semantic value" and thus "self-document" the code.

Comment: It seems sort of complex for a start but will surely try to implement it. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The random number is sometimes negative, that's why a character is skipper from `randomString` in those cases.

https://jsfiddle.net/ojbp0evz/3/

Use `Math.abs` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is HERE:

```
character = string.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length-1) + 0);
```

if your rand is less than 0, you will get a negative number, and therefor, you won't get any character. You must encapsulate your string.length-1 like so:

```
character = string.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * (string.length-1)));
```

Updated fiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ojbp0evz/4/)
Always remember: **MULTIPLICATIONS GOES FIRST!!**

**EDIT:** `string.length is 36`, you dont need to substract 1 to it, just multiply

```
character = string.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length));
```

Comment: This will never select the last character because random is `[0, 1)`.